# Django: Inserting twitter data to database

Tags: python, django

I want to  insert some data taken from twitter to django database. I got an error and I've tried all solutions on the internet. Nothing changes

**myproject/myapp/get_tweet.py**

```
from tweets.models import Tweet, TwitterUser
import tweepy
import time



def get_tweets(users, tweet_count):
    """
    users = list of tweeter users
    tweet_count = number of tweets planned to be fetched per user
    """

    consumer_key = #
    consumer_secret = #
    access_token = #
    access_token_secret = #

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)


    for user in users:
        try:
            image_url = api.get_user(user).profile_image_url_https
            db_user = TwitterUser(user_name=user, profile_image=image_url)
            db_user.save()
            user_id = api.get_user(user).id
            tweet_id = None
            count = tweet_count
            tweet_list = ['']

            #To fetch 10 tweets (except replies and retweets) if exist
            while count>0 and len(tweet_list)>0:

                tweet_list = api.user_timeline(id=user_id, count=tweet_count, max_id=tweet_id)

                for tweet in tweet_list:
                    tweet_id = tweet.id - 1
                    #Blocks replies and retweets of user
                    if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id==None and tweet.text[:4]!='RT @':
                        db_tweet = Tweet(user=db_user, date=tweet.created_at, tweet_text=tweet.text)
                        db_tweet.save()
                        count -= 1

        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(60*15)
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            break

get_tweets('twitter', 10)
```

Here what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdullahsecer/PycharmProjects/Test/tweets/get_tweet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tweets.models import Tweet, TwitterUser
  File "/home/abdullahsecer/PycharmProjects/Test/tweets/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class TwitterUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/abdullahsecer/PycharmProjects/Test/tweets/models.py", line 5, in TwitterUser
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

The error occurred when I tried to add data to database by adding these lines:

```
db_user = TwitterUser(user_name=user, profile_image=image_url)
db_user.save()

db_tweet = Tweet(user=db_user, date=tweet.created_at, tweet_text=tweet.text)
db_tweet.save()
```

Comment: Did you run the command in the django shell (`python manage.py shell)?

Comment: Read the error: _"You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings"_ ...the easiest way to do this is to run your code in the django shell. See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings